# ejb with ANT task

Tags: ant

Using ANT task with EJB....i need to create below few file...

ejb-jar.xml 
ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xmi 
ibm-ejb-jar-ext-pme.xmi 
ibm-ejb-jar-ext-pme51.xmi 
ibm-ejb-jar-ext.xmi

Any one please tell me how to write scripts using ANT....

and also which files i need to include for this file generate..

Please help with sample scripts for generate those files....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using EJB2 your best bet is to use [Xdoclet](http://xdoclet.sourceforge.net/xdoclet/ant/xdoclet/modules/ejb/EjbDocletTask.html) to generate the files for you, it can also generate a bunch of boilerplate java code that you will need as well.